# Can only one person with less than 2000 reputation approve a edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, support

I gave a edit suggestion and when it was approved I saw that only one person has approved it and that is the question owner with 16 reputation. How? Please explain me.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45556

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [*How do suggested edits work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> #### Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.
> - All users with the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) may vote on suggested edits to posts.

In other words, you only need 2000 reputation if you aren't the owner of the post.  The question owner can approve or reject any suggested edit to their post regardless of their reputation level.

This is intentional, not a bug.

Comment: Okay, but how can a question owner know about a suggested edit?

Comment: @Kirti They receive a notification in the top bar.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: It might be worth noting the effect of a moderator vote here, for completeness.

Comment: @snailplane A few of my posts were edited two days ago but I didn't receive any notifications. May I know the reason?

Comment: @గణేష్రెడ్డి http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/215040

Comment: @గణేష్రెడ్డి I believe [for this post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105771/how-to-use-verb-with-who) there was no notification because it was a tag-only edit.  That is the only post of yours I can find which was edited two days ago.

Comment: @snailplane Oh! Thanks for the link. I didn't literally mean two days ago. Another post was also edited five days ago and it was also a tag-only edit.